# Triangle Inequality on geodesic surfaces

Tags: geometry, geodesic

I am not well-versed in geometry relating to manifolds so pardon my lack of correct terminology.

Simply put, if I have some geometric surface (that can be found in the real physical world, such as the surface of a mountain range), and given 3 points $A, B, C$ on it.

Say I know the geodesic distance $AB$ and $AC$, now can I conclude that the geodesic distance $BC$ obeys the triangle inequality? (i.e. $AC \le AB + BC $)

Answer (score 0):

Geodesic distance on surface is infimum of lengths of curves. Hence
$|A-B| + |B-C|$ is sum of lengths of curves $c_i$ joining $A,\ B$
and $B,\ C$. That is, $c_1\bigcup c_2$ is also curve for $A$ and
$C$.